# SQL query to show if the value has end dated within parameter date range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table that has the following result `deduction_table`-

| Person_number | eff_date | eff_end_dt | Deduction_taken | deduction_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 27/12/2020 | 01/12/2020 | Health Insurance | 8.9 |
| 13 | 17/12/2020 | 31/12/4712 | Life Insurance | 9 |
| 14 | 18/11/2020 | 01/01/2021 | Sigma | 10 |

When I pass the parameter - from and to date as `25/12/2020` and `06/01/2021` I should get the following result -

| Person_number | change_date | Deduction_code | deduction_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 02/12/2020 | ~Health Insurance | 0 |
| 13 | 17/12/2020 | Life Insurance | 9 |
| 14 | 01/01/2021 | ~Sigma | 0 |

So when I pass the parameter `dates`, I Want that if there is an `effective end date` before the `to_date` passed in parameter, then
`deduction_amount` be 0 ,`deduction_code` should have **~** concattenated and the `change_date` be the next day after the `end date`.

Also, If this is not the case then the `change_Date` should the effective start only of the `deduction_table`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  person_number,
  case when eff_end_dt < incoming_date then eff_end_dt + 1 else eff_date end change_date,
  case when eff_end_dt < incoming_date then '~' end || Deduction_taken
```

should get you going